# How to use boost tests with SFML and cmake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, sfml, boost-test

I'm writing a simple game in C++ with use of SFML. I want to use boost tests, but when i try to i get undefined reference in every place i use SFML features (the game itself works fine, it's just the test that don't). Sample test:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "Sentry.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(BasicModelTestSuite)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testLamp_10BulbsWithPower10_ExpectedPower)
    {
        sf::Texture projectileTexture;
        sf::Texture sentryTexture;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sentry>> foes;
        sentryTexture.loadFromFile("../GameResources/sentry_image.png");
        projectileTexture.loadFromFile("../GameResources/projectile_animation.png");
        foes.push_back(std::make_shared<Sentry>(Sentry(&sentryTexture, sf::Vector2u(1,2), 0.2f, sf::Vector2f(140,200), projectileTexture, true)));
        foes.push_back(std::make_shared<Sentry>(Sentry(&sentryTexture, sf::Vector2u(1,2), 0.2f, sf::Vector2f(200,200), projectileTexture, false)));
        BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(foes.size(), 2);
    }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

And the test portion of cmakelist.txt:

```
ind_package(Boost 1.65 COMPONENTS "unit_test_framework" REQUIRED)

include_directories(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set(SOURCE_TEST_FILES
        test/master.cpp test/master.cpp test/baseTest.cpp
        main.cpp src/Level.cpp include/Level.h src/Game.cpp include/Game.h src/Platform.cpp include/Platform.h src/Item.cpp include/Item.h src/Life.cpp include/Life.h src/Coin.cpp include/Coin.h src/Collider.cpp include/Collider.h src/Enemy.cpp include/Enemy.h src/MrStrawberry.cpp include/MrStrawberry.h src/Animation.cpp include/Animation.h src/MrBerry.cpp include/MrBerry.h src/Projectile.cpp include/Projectile.h src/Sentry.cpp include/Sentry.h)

add_executable(TestProject ${SOURCE_TEST_FILES})

target_include_directories(TestProject PUBLIC include)

target_link_libraries(TestProject
        ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

enable_testing()

add_test(NAME Test COMMAND TestProject
        --report_level=detailed
        --log_level=all
        --color_output=yes)

add_custom_target(check ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL=all
        ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C $<CONFIGURATION> --verbose
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

I have no clue why it throws undefined reference to everything, like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/student/CLionProjects/oop21_ww2_14/BerryGame/src/Projectile.cpp:8: undefined reference to `sf::RectangleShape::setSize(sf::Vector2<float> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/student/CLionProjects/oop21_ww2_14/BerryGame/src/Projectile.cpp:9: undefined reference to `sf::Shape::setTexture(sf::Texture const*, bool)'
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question to add the solution. The solution should go in the answer space below the question. You can accept the answer that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestProject is missing the SFML library in the link options (see also [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)). Your main executable apparently *does* have it, but you don't show it.

Look for something like

```
 LINK_LIBRARIES(sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
```

Or target_link_libraries instead. If `LINK_LIBRARIES` is used, I suppose the target might need to be defined *after* that point.